# Firebase storage image won't append to array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

So I'm trying to download a set of images to display in a collectionview in my app. I have the images in the firebase storage, and their url in my database under the node "img" in each item node with a child "storage" with the url as the key.

I started by creating an empty array of UIImage: `var somePicArray = [UIImage]()` and then appending the pictures to this array through this funciton:

```
func test() {
    let penis = Database.database().reference().child("kategorier").child("brus")
    penis.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "img/storage")
            if let url = imageSnap.value as? String {
            let someRef = self.storageRef.reference(forURL: url)
                someRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 10024 * 10024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.testPicArray.append(image!)
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

up until the "if let url" line everything is ok, as I have tried printing the url within this if statement, and it prints the all the urls as strings perfectly.

however I'm a little more uncertain about the seccond part. I have used this block of code elsewhere in my app to display pictures from firebase storage and this works fine. However it does not seem to work within this funciton, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

In order to display the images in the cells I tried using the following code in the collectionview cellforitematindexpath method:

```
cell.cellimage.image = somePickArray[2]
```

I just chose a random number in the array to see if i can display any picture but it just crashes saying index out of range at this line, which I assume is because the array is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the vc appears the array is empty so

```
cell.cellimage.image = somePickArray[2]
```

will crash before array is filled with data , you need to make sure you do

```
return somePickArray.count
```

inside `numberOfItemsAtRow`

Comment: Nvm i got it to work now, had to change somePickArray[2] to somePickArray[indexpath.row] since it now displays the ammount of rows as the array contains items.